# Is there a shortcut for starting to edit/place curser at a search result (TexShop)?

Tags: shortcut

I am doing a lot of searching and subsequent editing.
I have not been able to find if a shortcut for starting to edit/placing the cursor were I have my search result (search here and google).
Currently using TexShop, but would also like to know for TexWorks.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you searching in the source or in the resulting pdf? I can't help with TeXShop, since that's mac only, but in TeXworks, searching in the source should automatically take you to the search result. If you're searching in the PDF, then ctrl-clicking (or right click -> jump to source) should take the cursor to the corresponding place in the source file.

Comment: When you search the result is selected. Simply -> or <- will move the cursor to the left or right side of that selection and cancel the selection.

Comment: Hi @frabjous I am searching in the source and what to start editing there.

Comment: Hi @HerbSchulz Thanks for your reply. However, that doesn't work on my end. If I use -> or <- after searching the cursor moves in the search-bar/word.

Comment: @IBDJ : try switching to the OgreKit search. When you press return to start the search it enables the Source pane. It’s also much more versatile allowing for regular expression searches of different flavors.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Thank you for this answer! That did it! Thank you.